# How to Maintain Consistency Across Instances with Global Variables in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, global-variables, distributed-system

I am working on a Python application deployed on Google App Engine. I profile all hits to my website and maintain the IP reputation score as a dictionary in a Global Variable.

Since a request can go to any instance of the service. How do I ensure that any state change in Global variable of an instance is visible/broadcasted to global variables of all other instances all the time. Essentially, all the global variables are synced in real time across instances of a service.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: How much of a latency do you have with memcache that you deem it to be high?

Comment: For accessing memcache, I observe a varied latency from 4ms to 15ms. Perhaps 10ms on average. I know that this is not bad though just wanting to further optimize performance